# How symmetrical can an organism be?

Tags: evolution, symmetry

The majority of living things have some form of symmetry.  Many mammals and fish have bi-symmetry, and anemones, starfish and jellyfish (among others) have radial symmetry.  However, there usually are many small or major differences that make them not perfectly symmetrical.  Is it possible for something to evolve to be 99% perfectly symmetrical, possibly even spherically?

Edit: I'm talking about something big, maybe as large as a cat or dog, not something tiny (ie. cocci bacteria).

Comment: Is there a specific scale you're interested in. Cocci bacteria are pretty spherical.

Comment: In short, no. As soon as you have a chambered heart, you have asymmetry.

Comment: Perfect spherical symmetry is impossible (at least, cellular organelles aren't spherical) but some organisms are way more symmetric than us. A lot of bilaterians doesn't have large asymmetrical organs like our liver, stomach or hearth.